# How to avoid using EEPROM instead of Flash memory?

Tags: c++, memory, arduino

A have made a temperature sensor device with Arduino MEGA. User may change the variable `int templimit` using buttons. The value of this variable is written to EEPROM so after restarts it will keep its last value. My problem is that on every restart I reduce the life time of the EEPROM.

**My question**: Is any way to avoid read/update from EEPROM and store the variable on onother memory?

**Save to EEPROM:**

```
void save_to_eeprom(unsigned int address, float config) { // (address, value)

  for (byte i = 0; i < sizeof(config); i++) { // size of config is 4
    EEPROM.write(address + i, reinterpret_cast<byte*>(&config)[i]);
  }
```

**Read from EEPROM:**

```
float read_from_eeprom(unsigned int address) { //(address)
  float config;
  for (byte i = 0; i < sizeof(config); i++) { // size of config is 4
    reinterpret_cast<byte*>(&config)[i] = EEPROM.read(address + i);
  }
  return config;
}
```

**This is how `templimit` will keep its last value after restart, the full code is:**

```
#include <EEPROM.h>


// this constant won't change:
const int  buttonPin = 8;    // up
const int  buttonPin1 = 3;    // down
const int  buttonPin2 = 2;    // enter


// Variables will change:
int buttonPushCounter;   // counter for the number of button presses
int buttonState;;  // up
int buttonState1;;  // down
int buttonState2;;  // enter
int templimit = read_from_eeprom(20); // temperature limit for alarm

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Update temperature limit if not wait 10 sec for time out");
  updatevalue();
  Serial.println("Done");
  Serial.println(templimit); // temperature limit for alarm

}


void loop() {
  // do nothing
}

int updatevalue(void) {
  int timenow;
  int timepassed;
  int counter = 10;

  timenow = millis();
  while (buttonState == LOW and buttonState1 == LOW and buttonState2 == LOW) { // this loop is just for 10 sec time out
    buttonState2 = digitalRead(buttonPin2); // enter
    buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin); //up
    buttonState1 = digitalRead(buttonPin1); // down
    timepassed = (millis() - timenow);
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println(counter--);
    if (timepassed >= 10000)
      return 0;
  }
  while (buttonState2 != HIGH) { // do this until enter is pressed

    buttonState2 = digitalRead(buttonPin2); // enter
    buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin); //up
    buttonState1 = digitalRead(buttonPin1); // down

    if (buttonState == HIGH) { // up
      buttonPushCounter++;
      Serial.print("number of button pushes:  ");
      Serial.println(buttonPushCounter);
    }
    if (buttonState1 == HIGH) { // down
      buttonPushCounter-- ;
      Serial.print("number of button pushes:  ");
      Serial.println(buttonPushCounter);
    }
    delay(700);
  }

  save_to_eeprom(20, buttonPushCounter); // save to address 20 tha value it can be negative

}
```

**My question**: Is any way to avoid read update from EEPROM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EEPROM is the right place for this kind of things.
(The only alternative I could think of is the flash memory, which has less write cycles, so that's even worse)

You say that "on every restart I reduce the life time of the EEPROM", which is not completely true. It's the write operation that reduces EEPROM life time. The write operation in your code takes place when user pressed enter. So you can reboot as much as you want without writing to the EEPROM.

Anyway, I think there is not much you can do if you want the settings to be persistent after an unexpected reboot. One small possible improvement however: Perform the write only if the new value differs from the old one.

The EEPROM has 100 000 write cycles, so you should be able to change the temperature limit that many times without failure.

Comment: I thought reading from EEPROM is reducing the life span. If it is right for my porpose ok.

Comment: Yes it should be. You can read EEPROM unlimited amount of times.